# How do I use RegEx to repeat a word pattern twice (with possible intervening whitespace)?

Tags: python

How do I repeat the same word two or more times in a row with possible varying intervening whitespace?

This is what I tried:

```
e = "bored         bored boredbored"
if re.search(r"{}\s*s/", e):
    print("The sequence " + e + " contains the same word written two or more times in a row with possible varying intervening whitespace.")
```

Comment: what are you expecting the output to be? that is not valid python syntax at all. Also `re.search` result is ignored

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will work:

```py
re.search(r"(\w+)\s+\1", e)
```

the parentheses around `\w+` define a group, and `\1` means "match whatever is in the first group".